# Set colors in pandastable

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python3.7 to create a table in a tkinter-window. For this table I would like to highlight certain cells/rows/columns. But I am just able to highlight columns via the statement

```
pt.columncolors[n[4]] = '#dcf1fc'
```

The following two lines seem to have no effect at all:

```
pt.rowcolors[4] = '#dcf1fc'
pt.setRowColors(rows=1, clr='#dcf1fc')
```

How can I highlight specific rows and specific cells?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

class MainClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
        self.main.title('Overview trading pairs')
        f = Frame(self.main)
        f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        df = TableModel.getSampleData()
        n = list(df.columns)
        pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=0, showstatusbar=0)
        pt.columncolors[n[4]] = '#dcf1fc'
        pt.rowcolors[4] = '#dcf1fc'
        pt.setRowColors(rows=1, clr='#dcf1fc')

        pt.show()
        return

app = MainClass()
#launch the app
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this question searching answer for similar problem.

After digging in source code of [setRowColors](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pandastable/core.html#Table.setRowColors) I found it can set every cell separatelly so you have to select columns using `cols=` because as default it uses `cols=None`

```
pt.setRowColors(rows=2, clr='blue',  cols=[1,3,5])
```

or you have to use `"all"` to select all columns

```
pt.setRowColors(rows=1, clr='green', cols='all')
```

---

As for `pt.rowcolors` - at start it is empty `DataFrame` without columns and rows and it has problem to set color correctly but if it used after `setRowColors` then it works correctly

```
    pt.setRowColors(rows=1, clr='green', cols='all')
    pt.rowcolors['date'] = 'green'
    pt.rowcolors['label'][5] = '#dcf1fc'
```

---

Eventually you would have to manually create columns and rows `rowcolors` at start.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    for c in df.columns:
        if c not in pt.rowcolors.columns:
            pt.rowcolors[c] = pd.Series(np.nan,index=df.index)
```

---

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class MainClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
        self.main.title('Overview trading pairs')
        f = Frame(self.main)
        f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        df = TableModel.getSampleData()

        names = list(df.columns)
        pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=0, showstatusbar=0)
        pt.show()

        pt.columncolors[names[4]] = '#dcf1fc'
        pt.columncolors['label'] = 'red'


        print('--- rowcolors ---')
        print(pt.rowcolors) # empty 

        #pt.rowcolors['label'] = '#dcf1fc' # error 

        #for c in df.columns:
        #    if c not in pt.rowcolors.columns:
        #        pt.rowcolors[c] = pd.Series(np.nan,index=df.index)

        pt.setRowColors(rows=1, clr='green', cols='all')
        pt.setRowColors(rows=2, clr='blue',  cols=[1,3,5])

        pt.rowcolors['date'] = 'green'
        #pt.rowcolors[ ['date','label'] ] = 'green'

        pt.rowcolors['label'][5] = '#dcf1fc'
        pt.rowcolors['label'][5,10] = '#dcf1fc'

        print('--- rowcolors ---')
        print(pt.rowcolors)

app = MainClass()
app.mainloop()
```