# subset dataframe to show on GUI Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I have dropdown option in tkinter which select the option of dropdown by groupby the col1 by dataframe pandas , Now I am able to see the subset of dataframe by clicking ok button in my terminal , I want to see the subset dataframe after selecting into dropdown in my GUI , 
Please let me know how to see the subset dataframe a/c to dropdown option into my GUI .

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---

def on_click():

    val = selected.get()
    if val == 'all':
        print(df)
    else:
        df2 = df[ df['TIME'] == val ]
        print(df2)


        def showdata():

            row, column = df2.shape

            for r in range(row):
                for c in range(column):
                    e1 = tk.Entry(Frame1)
                    e1.insert(1, df2.iloc[r, c])
                    e1.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=2, pady=2)
                    e1.config(state='disabled')
                    # print(df.groupby(''))
                    # exit()

        Exitbutton = tk.Button(Frame1, text="EXIT", fg="red", bd=5, width=3, height=2, command=root.quit)
        Exitbutton.pack()
        #Exitbutton.grid(row=41, column=2)
        nextbutton = tk.Button(Frame1, text="Next Data", fg="red", bd=5, width=7, height=2,command=showdata)
        nextbutton.pack()
        #nextbutton.grid(row=41, column=3)




# --- main ---

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': ['00:00','00:00','01:00','01:00','02:00','02:00'],
    'A': ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
    'B': ['x','x','y','y','z','z'],
})

root = tk.Tk()
Frame1=tk.Frame(root,bd=5)

values = ['all'] + list(df['TIME'].unique())
selected = tk.StringVar()

options = tk.OptionMenu(Frame1, selected, *values)
options.pack()

button = tk.Button(Frame1, text='OK', command=on_click)
button.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(Frame1, text='OK', command=on_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I am getting blank Tkinter Window , without using showdata function i am getting dropdown option and data are showing in terminal but i want the subset dataframe to display on GUI for that i created showdata() but it is not working. 
Kindly let me know how to solve this issue , I will be appreciable

** For more details on dropdown options show you can go below link 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890350/dropdown-option-to-show-subset-of-dataframe-tkinter)

Comment: `Frame1.pack()` to show frame.

Comment: use `Frame1`  to put only `Entry` using `grid()`. Other elements put directly in `root` using `pack()`

Comment: I added my last code from previous question and I added method to change table after selectiong option without pressing code. I also working on small example with [pandastable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable) which seems more useful then manuall creating table.

Comment: Yes , Pandastable is very easy and useful , i think i should try pandastable also for visualization data into it .
By Reading the Documenatation of Pandastable isn''t it i will be able to learn the Pandastable or any other way to learn pandastable you can guide ?

Comment: I made example with pandastable in answer below. There are some [basic examples](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) in doc but there is also full working tool [DataExplore](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataexplore.html) and its souce code can be useful as example.

Answer (score 1):

It is my last code from previous question

**EDIT:** I added `command=` to `OptionMenu` so now it doesn't need `Button` to accept selection.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---

def showdata():
    global table

    # destroy old frame with table
    if table:
        table.destroy()

    # create new frame with table         
    table = tk.Frame(frame_data)
    table.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # fill frame with table
    row, column = df2.shape
    for r in range(row):
        for c in range(column):
            e1 = tk.Entry(table)
            e1.insert(1, df2.iloc[r, c])
            e1.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=2, pady=2)
            e1.config(state='disabled')

def on_click():
    global df2

    val = selected.get()

    if val == 'all':
        df2 = df
        #next_button.grid_forget()
    else:
        df2 = df[ df['TIME'] == val ]
        #next_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    print(df2)
    showdata()
    next_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

def on_select(val):
    global df2

    if val == 'all':
        df2 = df
        #next_button.grid_forget()
    else:
        df2 = df[ df['TIME'] == val ]
        #next_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    print(df2)
    showdata()
    next_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

# --- main ---

frame_data = None

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': ['00:00','00:00','01:00','01:00','02:00','02:00'],
    'A': ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
    'B': ['x','x','y','y','z','z'],
})

root = tk.Tk()

values = ['all'] + list(df['TIME'].unique())
selected = tk.StringVar()

options = tk.OptionMenu(root, selected, *values, command=on_select)
options.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_click)
button.pack()

# frame for table and button "Next Data"
frame_data = tk.Frame(root)
frame_data.pack()

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="EXIT", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack() 

# table with data - inside "frame_data" - without showing it
table = tk.Frame(frame_data)
#table.grid(row=0, column=0)

# buttom "Next Data" - inside "frame_data" - without showing it
next_button = tk.Button(frame_data, text="Next Data", command=showdata)
#next_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Example with [pandastable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable) is shorter and it has built-in function in mouse right click - like sorting

[image]

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table

# --- functions ---

def on_select(val):

    if val == 'all':
        pt.model.df = df
    else:
        pt.model.df = df[ df['TIME'] == val ]

    # refresh/redraw table in window
    pt.redraw()

# --- main ---

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': ['00:00','00:00','01:00','01:00','02:00','02:00'],
    'A': ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
    'B': ['x','x','y','y','z','z'],
})

root = tk.Tk()

# create frame for pandas table
table_frame = tk.Frame(root)
table_frame.pack()

# add pandastable do frame
pt = Table(table_frame, dataframe=df) # it can't be `root`, it has to be `frame` 
pt.show()
pt.setRowColors(cols=[2], rows=[2, 3], clr='green')

values = ['all'] + list(df['TIME'].unique())
selected = tk.StringVar()

options = tk.OptionMenu(root, selected, *values, command=on_select)
options.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you alot for helping me,
I want to add one more feature in col B where ever x is there there x color become green, y then y cell color red and z then cell color blue , 
I think we can do by table.colorbyvalue() but i am not able to findout the example of it ,Any link for colorbyvalue() ?

Comment: I founld only [Table Coloring](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/wiki/Table-Coloring) and source code for [setRowColors](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pandastable/core.html#Table.setRowColors) which can set color for every cell separatelly `pt.setRowColors(cols=[2], rows=[2, 3], clr='green')`

Comment: create new question on new page and more people will see it and there will be place for new answer. I found similar question [Set colors in pandastable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448763/set-colors-in-pandastable/) and I made answer with example.

Comment: By using    
pt.setRowColors(cols=[2], rows=[2, 3], clr='green')
I am getting an Error 
 pt.setRowColors(cols=[2], rows=[2, 3], clr='green')
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'setRowColors'
Even I have used pt.columncolors['B'] = '#dcf1fc' , same Error is coming

Comment: when I use `pt.setRowColors(cols=[2], rows=[2, 3], clr='green')` in my last code in answer then it changes color. Maybe your object `Table` is not from `pandastable`. BTW: I added `pt.setRowColors(cols=[2], rows=[2, 3], clr='green')` to code in example but you should creae new question on new page and you will have place to show code which you used and full error message which you get.

Comment: same code if i am running then i am getting error 
    pt.setRowColors(cols=[2], rows=[2, 3], clr='green')
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'setRowColors'

Comment: create new question on new page - you will have space to show full code which makes this problem. It seems your `Table` is not `pandastable.Table`

Comment: I created new question , link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077046/set-color-of-cell-of-one-column-based-on-value-of-column-cell-example-pandastabl
i want b column cell value color to change , if x then green & if y value then red ,
Thank you.