# SET Color of Cell of one column based on value of column cell Example pandastable

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, tkinter

I have dataframe and i am using pandastable to show the data gui , I want to show different  color in my B column , if B column has 'X' as a value then show green cell x else if 'Y' value then show red cell color.

I know we can do by table.setColorbyValue() but i am not getting the example to table.setColorbyValue()
can you please tell me how to use table.setColorbyValue()

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table

# --- functions ---

def on_select(val):

    if val == 'all':
        pt.model.df = df
    else:
        pt.model.df = df[ df['TIME'] == val ]

    # refresh/redraw table in window
    pt.redraw()

# --- main ---

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': ['00:00','00:00','01:00','01:00','02:00','02:00'],
    'A': ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
    'B': ['x','x','y','y','z','z'],
})

root = tk.Tk()

# create frame for pandas table
table_frame = tk.Frame(root)
table_frame.pack()

# add pandastable do frame
pt = Table(table_frame, dataframe=df) # it can't be `root`, it has to be `frame` 
pt.show()


values = ['all'] + list(df['TIME'].unique())
selected = tk.StringVar()

options = tk.OptionMenu(root, selected, *values, command=on_select)
options.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59896174/1832058) you have example how to use it `setRowColors`for this - and it works. If you get error then show your code and full error message.

Comment: I tried to understand source code for [setColorbyValue](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pandastable/core.html#Table.setColorbyValue) and it seems it works only with columns which have integer/float values and it need to set these columns in list `pt.multiplecollist = [...]` before you use `setColorbyValue()`. Other problem is to assign colors to values which is made by function `pt.values_to_colors` - so you would have to overwrite this function. All seems too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Example with `setColorByValue()` but I think this function will not be so useful as you expect. Frankly, I don't understand why this function exists.

---

You have to set which columns to colorized and later run `setColorbyValue()` but columns may need integer or float values. Or at least it will not work with strings.

```
pt.multiplecollist = [0, 2] # column's number
pt.setColorbyValue()       # set colors using `pt.values_to_colors()`
```

Other problem: it open Dialog window and ask for some color.

[image]

Based on source code: [setColorbyValue](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pandastable/core.html#Table.setColorbyValue)

---

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'B': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'C': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
})

root = tk.Tk()

table_frame = tk.Frame(root)
table_frame.pack()

pt = Table(table_frame, dataframe=df) # it can't be `root`, it has to be `frame` 
pt.show()

pt.multiplecollist = [0,2] # column's number
pt.setColorbyValue() # set colors using `pt.values_to_colors()` 

root.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** more useful can be `setColorByMask()`

```
mask_1 = pt.model.df['A'] < 5

pt.setColorByMask('A', mask_1, 'red')

mask_2 = pt.model.df['A'] >= 5

pt.setColorByMask('A', mask_2, 'green')
```

---

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'B': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'C': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
})

root = tk.Tk()

table_frame = tk.Frame(root)
table_frame.pack()

pt = Table(table_frame, dataframe=df) # it can't be `root`, it has to be `frame` 
pt.show()

mask_1 = pt.model.df['A'] < 5
pt.setColorByMask('A', mask_1, 'red')
mask_2 = pt.model.df['A'] >= 5
pt.setColorByMask('A', mask_2, 'green')

root.mainloop()
```