# How to style pandas dataframe and apply them to a pandastable Table?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I'm trying to apply one or more styles to a `pandas` Dataframe, but I can't get to display the applied style in a `pandastable` Table. Here's an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
class TestApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
        self.main.title('Table app')
        f = Frame(self.main)
        f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        df = TableModel.getSampleData()
        df.style.highlight_max(color='lightgreen') #HERE'S THE STYLE I WANT TO APPLY
        pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
        pt.show()
        return

app = TestApp()
app.mainloop()
```

This will display the usual Table with no styles applied.

Does pandastable process the html/css style created by the pandas Styler or is there any way to apply styles to a pandastable Table object?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please Check this https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkinter-pandastable-examples-gb.html for Color Columns part

Comment: Thanks. That goes as far as table coloring, but what if I want to change just the text color in a specific row based on a mask instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could use function setColorByMask():

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

class TestApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
        self.main.title('Table app')
        f = Frame(self.main)
        f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        df = TableModel.getSampleData()
        pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
        for col_idx in range(len(df.columns)):
            col_name = pt.model.df.iloc[:, col_idx].name
            if pt.model.df[col_name].dtypes != 'object':
                pt.setColorByMask(
                    col_name, 
                    pt.model.df.iloc[:, col_idx] == pt.model.df.iloc[:, col_idx].max(), 
                    'lightgreen'
                )
        pt.show()
        return

app = TestApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Some details are also provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60078298/2792888).

Comment: I've got the setColorByMask figured out, except for pt.model.df, that will not be executed even if I call pt.updateModel(TableModel(df)). So my final string is: self.pt.setColorByMask(col='Fee', clr='#FFD700', mask=(self.df['Fee']==self.df['Fee'].max())). Just to clarify, pandastable can stretch as far as table coloring, but it won't process a pd.DataFrame Styler if I apply any style as df.style.applymap(some style) for example?

Comment: As far as I know pandastable is not so advanced yet.